# Are font sizes in pt and px always look the same?

Tags: html, fonts

Will "pixels" always look the same as "points"?

```
<p style="font-size: 16px;">
    pixels
</p>
<p style="font-size: 12pt;">
    points
</p>
```

**UPDATE:**

I know difference btw pixels and points, please, just answer my question, I do not need extra articles!

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6390169/894872

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pixels vs. Points in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389914/pixels-vs-points-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. It depends on things such as browser and OS. They have to calculate the pixels from the value you give in points. The problem is the ppi (pixels per inch) is not the same for all systems. It should be 72 ppi I think, but it is different across different platforms like 96 ppi or 80 ppi.

Answer (score 0):

```
Points are much like Pixels
```

and

```
Pixels are much like Points.
```

But `not look Same` It depends on Browser and OS.

Go to this **[link](http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html)** here they give the `Approximate Conversion from Points to Pixels`