# HTML Image tag - Define size in Points

Tags: html, image, tags

Is the following html valid...?

```
   <img src="image.gif" style="height:400pt; width:400pt;" alt="image" />
```

Comment: Browsers are very, very poor at rendering point units correctly. They should be avoided for use on screen.

Comment: So, you want to know how to get the size of the image in points based on their size in pixels?

Comment: I want to know if its possile to define height/width in points?Something like I have mentioned above...is this the right mark up or not??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read this article on W3c:

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

And if you are decided to use points, you can get some tips here:

[Pixels vs. Points in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389914/pixels-vs-points-in-html)

and a "conversion table" from pixel to point can be found here:

http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/points-pixels.html

Comment: Provide answers, not links.