# How big in 1pt?

Tags: css, dpi, ppi

i really need to know this. Everyone (hopefully) knows that dpi dont matter on the web, it doesnt matter if you save and image with 4000 or just 1 dpi, you computer just shows it point to pixel.
Now, what about css and font size in pt? Many websites say that windows uses 96 dpi and mac 72 what means that 1 pt on mac is 1 px and on windows 1,333 px.
But this makes no sense, the os has nothing to do with any resolutions, only the screen has PPI, not dpi. And the ppi depend on the screen.

Is it true that 1pt is 1px on mac and 1,333px on pc?

Comment: In addition to being too broad, the question is based on wrong assumptions. Start from reading what CSS Values and Units Module Level 3 (CR) says about distance units.

Answer (score 3):

[This is quite a good read on the subject](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

> Points (pt): Points are traditionally used in print media (anything
>   that is to be printed on paper, etc.). One point is equal to 1/72 of
>   an inch. Points are much like pixels, in that they are fixed-size
>   units and cannot scale in size.

[See this article from W3C](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

> The so-called absolute units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in
>   CSS as everywhere else. A length expressed in any of these will appear
>   as exactly that size (within the precision of the hardware and
>   software). They are not recommended for use on screen, because screen
>   sizes vary so much. A big screen may be 60cm (24in), a small, portable
>   screen is maybe only 8cm. And you don't look at them from the same
>   distance.
>
> The relation between the absolute units is as follows: 1in = 2.54cm =
>   25.4mm = 72pt = 6pc

As such on a 72 PPI (pixels per inch) display, 1 pixel=1 point, so yes on a Mac if PPI is 72, 1pt = 1px, and on a Windows machine if PPI is 96, then 1pt=1.3'px.

[The 72 for mac and 96 for Windows are only defaults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) however, and may vary depending on available hardware and system settings.

> **[Points are for print? Nope.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389914/pixels-vs-points-in-html)**
>
> Points are not for print exclusively. Theoretically, points are for
>   defining an absolute measure. Pixels are not absolute, since depending
>   on your screen and chosen definition (not resolution), the resolution
>   (pixels per inch) can go from a lot (150dpi) or very little (75dpi).
>   Which means your pixels can be a size, or maybe half that size. Which
>   means that text you design to be perfectly legible on your screen may
>   look too big on your client’s screen (“please make the text smaller,
>   ok?”) or too small to be readable on your neighbor’s screen (“hey, the
>   website you told me about the other day? the one you said you had
>   worked on… well i couldn’t read the text very well, it’s so small”).
>
> Points are a solution to this issue. But browsers and operating
>   systems need to manage those. Basically, it means:
>
> browsers have to calculate the display size in pixels using the given
>   value (say, 10pt) and the screen’s real resolution; operating systems
>   have to communicate the real current resolution, and not a default
>   value.

Also, [take a look at this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference), [and this article](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/typemeasurements/a/aa042803a.htm)

Comment: But the ppi depend on the screen, and the os never really knows how many ppi your screen has! Does the OS just assume that your screen has 72/96 ppi?

Comment: Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#Computer_monitor_DPI_standards

Comment: Thanks alot, i was looking for something just like this !