# Css Text & Font Manipulation

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts

What are the differences and implications of applying Css to some element in mobile application such as:

1. .content{ font-size:80%;}
2. .content{ font-size:10px;}
3. .content{ font-size:1em;}

And how does this affects elements `letter-spacing`, `line-height` and `word-spacing` .

In addition what is typical different in `font-style: oblique` and `italic`.

Comment: google is your friend: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [pxtoem](http://pxtoem.com/)  it depend on what you want to do if it is [responsive](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) or not and how you would like your UI to be.

[image]

**Pixels (px):**

Pixels are fixed-size units that are used in screen media (i.e. to be read on the computer screen). One pixel is equal to one dot on the computer screen (the smallest division of your screen’s resolution). Many web designers use pixel units in web documents in order to produce a pixel-perfect representation of their site as it is rendered in the browser. One problem with the pixel unit is that it does not scale upward for visually-impaired readers or downward to fit mobile devices.

**Points (pt):**

Points are traditionally used in print media (anything that is to be printed on paper, etc.). One point is equal to 1/72 of an inch. Points are much like pixels, in that they are fixed-size units and cannot scale in size.

**Percent (%):**

The percent unit is much like the “em” unit, save for a few fundamental differences. First and foremost, the current font-size is equal to 100% (i.e. 12pt = 100%). While using the percent unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for accessibility.

[Read more](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

[Why em instead of px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609517/why-em-instead-of-px)

[Pixels vs. Points in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389914/pixels-vs-points-in-html)

Comment: Thank you Kougiland, you a good instructor. you save me out this confusion.