# Ionic: how to set same font in span tag for different resolutions?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have the following div with inner spans:

```
<!-- Debug info -->
        <div class="helperInfo" ng-if="learningModeState == true">
            <span ng-if="activeCandle != null">Active candle : {{activeCandle}} |</span>
            <span ng-if="activeCandle == null">Active candle : 0 |</span>
            <span ng-if="selectedCandle != null">Selected candle: {{selectedCandle}} |</span>
            <span ng-if="selectedCandle == null">Selected candle: None |</span>
            <span>Volume: {{micVolume}} |</span>
            <span>Treshold: {{micTreshold}} |</span>
        </div>
```

And related css:

```
.helperInfo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    height: 8%;
    text-align: center;
}

.helperInfo span {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Problem is that font size is good resolutions about 640 x 320 in landscape, but if i'm trying to set resolution of the device for example to 1920 x 1080 i always get font smaller than for resolution 640 px (see image below).

[image]

What i should to set to get same sizes and proportions fro different sizes?

Viewport is set to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

body:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

whole template is:

```
<ion-view class="gameBgImage" >
    <ion-content ng-init="animateGameScreen()" scroll="false" >

        <!-- Debug info -->
        <div class="helperInfo" ng-if="learningModeState == true">
            <span ng-if="activeCandle != null">Active candle : {{activeCandle}} |</span>
            <span ng-if="activeCandle == null">Active candle : 0 |</span>
            <span ng-if="selectedCandle != null">Selected candle: {{selectedCandle}} |</span>
            <span ng-if="selectedCandle == null">Selected candle: None |</span>
            <span>Volume: {{micVolume}} |</span>
            <span>Treshold: {{micTreshold}} |</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Moving spider on the net -->
        <img id="movingSpiderOnNet" src="img/objects/spiderOne.gif">

        <!-- Moving cloud-->
        <img id="cloudLeftToRightGamePage" src="img/objects/cloud_left_right.png">

        <!-- Spider-->
        <img id="spiderTwo" src="img/objects/spiderOne.gif">

        <!-- START SHRINKING SPIDER NET-->
        <div id="shrinkingSpiderNetTwo">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <!-- //END SHRINKING SPIDER NET-->

        <!-- Bat start
        <div id="bat_1">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
-->
        <!-- // Bat end -->


        <!-- Candles start -->
        <div id="candle_1">
            <div class="candleFlame" id="candleFlame_1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="fallingDropWax1_right">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div id="candle_2">
            <div class="candleFlame" id="candleFlame_2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="fallingDropWax2_right">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div id="candle_3">
            <div class="candleFlame" id="candleFlame_3">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="fallingDropWax3_right">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div id="candle_4">
            <div class="candleFlame" id="candleFlame_4">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="fallingDropWax4_right">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- // Candles end -->

        <!-- Sidebar menu start -->
        <div id="menuRightSideGame" >
            <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
                <div class="fa fa-repeat fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="resetGame();" id="resetGameIcon"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightSideMenuItem">
                <div class="fa fa-close fa-2x rightSideMenuItemIcon" ng-click="cancelGame();" id="cancelGameIcon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- // Sidebar menu start -->
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How about setting a font size in `vw`.

Comment: There is no mention on the Google developers website about vw meassure units :
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/UseLegibleFontSizes

Comment: But there are more length units than that. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/

Comment: Or did you mean you wanted to restrict yourself to length units on that page? In that case, I would suggest using a bunch of @media queries with different font sizes in each.

Answer (score 0):

For that span use either point (pt) or percentage (%), don't use pixels as they physically represent different size in different resolution. Please check this also : [Pixels vs. Points in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389914/pixels-vs-points-in-html)

Comment: hmm, check this comparison if that helps : http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/